# How to open a Bing Maps from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, bing-maps

I would like to pass and address to and open Bing Maps from a vb.net app. Anywhere I can find an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to check out the [Bing Maps Web Services SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980922.aspx). It allows you to use Bing to [Geocode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966817(loband).aspx) (retrieve a location from an address) as well as [Download Imagery Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981090.aspx). Another place for Bing developers information can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/).

Edit: I just reread your question and I think you can do what you need using a simple string concatenation to create a url. This might work:

```
Dim MyURL As String
Dim Location As String
Location = "Pittsburgh, PA"
MyURL = "http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&where1=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Location) + "&encType=1"
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(MyURL)
```

My VB is a little rusty, but this should get you started. You will also need to import the System.Web Namespace for the HttpUtility Class.

Refrences:

- [Launch Browser from VB.NET](http://www.mredkj.com/vbnet/OpenURL.html)
- [HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)
- [Bing URL Parameters](http://help.live.com/Help.aspx?market=en-US&project=WL_Local&querytype=topic&query=WL_LOCAL_PROC_BuildURL.htm)

Comment: I'm interested in the snipped you provided. I tried it but I'm getting "Interenet Explorer cannot display this page".

Comment: It seemed to work for me, can you copy the URL out of the IE toolbar after it pops up?

Comment: Seems to be working now here too. Thaks. Anyway to have it open w/o the panel on the left that contains the address and other info?

Comment: The only way I could see to do that would be to create your own web page with an embedded map using the http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try the [nerd dinner asp.net mvc tutorial](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html).  It's near the end and you can download a working example.

Answer (score 0):

'In addition to kersney's example this uses the webbrowser control in a vb form

Imports System.Web

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Location As String = "Pittsburgh, PA"
    Dim MyURL As String = "http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&where1=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Location)
    Dim WebBrowser1 As New WebBrowser
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized 'maximize window
    Me.Controls.Add(WebBrowser1) 'add browser control
    WebBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill   'fill to form
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(MyURL) 'display page in form
End Sub
```